# Visual C# : cannot connect to local SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to my local SQL express database with following code with no luck :

```
string strConnectionString = null;
SqlConnection cnn = null;
strConnectionString = "Data Source=" + txtSQLServer.Text.Trim() + ";Initial Catalog=" + txtSQLDatabase.Text.Trim() + ";User ID=user;Password=user";
cnn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

MessageBox.Show(strConnectionString);
try
{
    cnn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Open ! ");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

The sql express database is running, because I can connect with it through SQL server management studio.
I already tried "localhost", "127.0.0.1", "PC-name/SQLEXPRESS"

error says : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

What more can I try?

edit : ok, found the problem

1. I needed to start the SQL server browser
2. connect to "PC-name/SQLEXPRESS"

But in the future I want to connect to an IP-address, how do I do this?

I tried this connection string :

```
strConnectionString = "Data Source=" + txtSQLServer.Text.Trim() + ",1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=" + txtSQLDatabase.Text.Trim() + ";User ID=user;Password=user";
```

Comment: The error message basically says that it cannot find the server, so the server name is wrong or the server is down. If you can connect with SSMS, use the exactly same server name as you use with it.

Comment: As a minor improvement, it's usually better to use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` rather than concatenating strings to form the connections string.

Comment: If you want to connect using an IP you would use <IPADDRESS>\SQLEXPRESS in the connection string.